# Rømer wheels in TikZ - wrong length of the spiral arc?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a pair of so called Rømer wheels:

[image]

These are two logarithmic spirals rolling on each other, one clockwise and the other counterclockwise, but my equation for rotation angle of the second wheel by given angle of the first wheel seem to be wrong (I'm using polar coordinates).

[image]

Here is the TikZ code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=0.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]

    \draw[line cap=round, line width=0.2mm, domain=0:2*pi, variable=\t, samples=100, yshift=8.0072mm, rotate around={-100:(0,0)}]
        plot[fixed point arithmetic] ({\t r}:{1.2*exp(0.4*\t)}) -- cycle;

    \draw[line cap=round, line width=0.2mm, domain=0:2*pi, variable=\t, samples=100, yshift=-8.0072mm, rotate around={90.6709:(0,0)}]
        plot[fixed point arithmetic] ({\t r}:{1.2*exp(0.4*\t)}) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image]

Comment: You don't seem to use the formula you have given as an image. What are `r` values? And can you complete your MWE with the necessary libraries etc.

Comment: What's the relation between the function you've given in terms of `sin` and the function you are using to draw the wheels? Even the number of variables seems to differ.

Comment: Is your curve the same as Fibonacci spiral? http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fibonacci-spiral/

Comment: And what is the desired output? The one in the attached image?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use length as the parameter. And then `ln` it.

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\def\n{30}\def\.{.71828}
\foreach\r in{1,...,\n}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\s{1+\r*1\./\n}
    \tikz{
        \fill[black](-3,-3)rectangle(3,6\.);
        \draw[white,line cap=round,domain=1:2\.,variable=\t,samples=100]
            plot[shift={(0,3\.)},rotate={-360*ln(    \s)-90}]({360*ln(    \t)}:{    \t})--cycle
            plot[shift={(0,  0)},rotate={-360*ln(3\.-\s)+90}]({360*ln(3\.-\t)}:{3\.-\t})--cycle;
    }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, looks great. I'll try to figure out that does every single parameter mean :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]

    % Largest radius 
    \def\l{3.25};           

    % Rotation angle in radians
    \def\a{1.2*pi};

    % Second parameter of the spiral
    \def\b{0.25}

    \begin{scope}[rotate=-90]

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\shift}{{\l*exp(\b*2*pi)+\l}}                  
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{ln((\shift - \l*exp(\b*\a))/\l)/\b}    

        % Spiral (bottom)   
        \begin{scope}[rotate around={{180-deg(\angle)}:(0, 0)}]
            \draw[line width=0.075mm, domain=0:2*pi, variable=\t, samples=500]
                plot[fixed point arithmetic] ({\l*exp(\b*\t)*cos(deg(\t))}, {\l*exp(\b*\t)*sin(deg(\t))}) -- cycle;     
        \end{scope} 

        % Spiral (top)                  
        \begin{scope}[rotate around={{-deg(\a)}:(-\shift, 0)}]
            \draw[line width=0.075mm, domain=0:2*pi, variable=\t, samples=500]
                plot[fixed point arithmetic] ({-\shift + \l*exp(\b*\t)*cos(deg(\t))}, {\l*exp(\b*\t)*sin(deg(\t))}) -- cycle;   
        \end{scope}                                     
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]